# Add custom delimiter in key-value form data

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I have data which are in "Key:value" form where keys are `901`,`902`,`903`,`904` and respective values are `S`,`M`,`F,`WAP`, with space as delimiter.

- Input example

  ```
  901 S 902 M 903 F 904 WAP .....
  ```

I want to convert into `key:value,key:value` format.

- Desired output:

  ```
  901:S,902:M,903:F,904:WAP .....
  ```

I tried using `sed` but I was only able to add asingle delimiter.

Comment: Is it a requirement to only use `sed`, or are other standard tools an option, too?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -E 's/\s*([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z]+)/\1:\2,/g;s/,$//' <<< '901 S 902 M 903 F 904 WAP'
-------8<------------------
901:S,902:M,903:F,904:WAP
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace every odd space with a colon and every even space with a comma.

```
sed -E 's/ ([^ ]) /:\1,/g; s/ /:/'
```

The second substitution replaces the last remaining space with a colon - it's not replaced by the first substitution as there's no comma to go with it.

Comment: It's been working over over till specified length.

--->> sed -E 's/ ([^ ]) /:\1,/g; s/ /:/' <<< '901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC 907 31 908 371 909 PLMN 913 NA 920'

O/P :: 901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC:907 31 908 371 909 PLMN 913 NA 920

Expected O/P :: 901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC:907:31,908:371,909:PLMN,913:NA,920: and so on.

Comment: I don't understand. If your actual data is different to what you showed in the question, either edit the question, or ask a new one.